# build Windows EXE (or big jar) from scala-3 project

Tags: scala, scala-3

I have a Scala 3 project and need to build a binary which runs on machines where installing Java is possible, but I don’t want to install Scala there (because I want to be able to determine Scala versions solely on the dev side).

And I don’t want to build an installer file, because the file will get updated quite often.

I have a `/src/main/scala/main.scala` with

```
@main
def main(): Unit =
```

etc, and this is my `build.sbt` so far:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.3.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "foo",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.2.0",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "2.1.0",
    libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "os-lib" % "0.9.1",
    libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "requests" % "0.8.0",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.15" % Test,
  )

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature")
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using [sbt native packager - windows](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/windows.html)?

Comment: Or you can also use [sbt native packager - jdk](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/jdkpackager.html)

Comment: Also, does it have to be an `.exe`? If you already have **Java** installed and the project is small, you can just create an uber JAR: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: @GastónSchabas I had a brief look at those. The first does only seem to build MSI files, right? And the second one has this `jdkPackagerType` = `exe` option, but I do not understand what the result is supposed to be. Is it also an installer (which I do not want)? Does the EXE also contain Scala? and Java? I have no clue what it does.

Comment: @Marcus that is an **sbt** plugin, **sbt** `1.x` is written in `2.12` thus plugins are only published for `2.12`. But, just like **sbt** can compile any **Scala** version, the plugins work with any **Scala** version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to build a big jar. This way I still need Java at the target machine, but not Scala. At first I was not sure, because I could not find any version for Scala 3, but ([as LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77953288/build-windows-exe-from-scala-3-project?noredirect=1#comment137443045_77953288)) sbt plugins work with any (target) Scala version.

I had to add a file `project/plugins.sbt` containing:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "2.1.5")
```

And in `build.sbt` I configured the main class and target file name/location inside `.settings(` like this:

```
    assembly / mainClass := Some("main"),
    assembly / assemblyJarName := "../../foo.jar",
```

I tried to use `assemblyOutputPath` instead of adding the path to `assemblyJarName`, but that deleted the whole project , so I do not dare to use that again.

`sbt assembly` builds the big jar and at the target machines I just do: `java -jar foo.jar`